# PHP Live or Run Error Highlighter for Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Hi everyone i am using Sublime Text 3.
I have search a lot for php live or Run time error highlighter when i am typing my php on sublime just like in Dreamweaver it highlights the line where the error is but i did not find anything.all i get is sublimelinter i have installed it but it did not work for me.Also i have check php syntax checker but it is to old only used for sublime text 2.

can anyone suggest me where i download it or install it using my package control it will be really helpful...

Comment: You are looking for [Sublime Linter, specifically its PHP plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-php).

Comment: @LeonidShevtsov i have tried it but it is not working bro... :( can you suggest another one...

Comment: Yeah Tried it but it did not work for me can you suggest another one...

Comment: if sublimelinter has been installed. you must install sublimelinter plugin too, use `sublimlinter-` as keyword at package control's search and all result is plugin for sublimelinter. for simple php live validation, you can install `sublimelinter-php` plugin.